# Excel Text Colour Formatting

Tags: excel, colors, fonts, format, rules

How do I create a rule that automatically applies the Font colour from column B, to the text in column A?

So I want A2 to take it's colour from B2, A3 to take it's colour from B3, and so on

for example, if I have 3 columns with name, gender, and age. I want both the name and gender to show orange for a boy, and purple for a girl, but I don't want the other columns to change.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75857020/edit) to clarify existing data, expected result and what you have tried so far.

Comment: If font color in column B is set by conditional formatting - use same rules, if colors are set manually you will need VBA code.

Comment: @ user11222393 How?             I don't see how to say if value in "b" is "x", make corresponding cell in  "a" green

Comment: @Julie you could start here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: I don't see anything there that says how to format column a based on values in column b. ty for trying though

Comment: nvm, huge headache but finally worked it out, but for anyone else interested you need to use the formula section of the rule and type =$B1="your word" where B1 is the first cell in the column you want to take the info from, and the destination cell is entered in the usual manner